# Uneditable text in an answer?

Tags: support, bug, edits, markdown

I stumbled onto [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4096311/6045800). It has some fluff I wanted to edit out. Specifically, this *"Hi @dany:"* in the start.

But, to my surprise, that phrase disappears when entering edit mode. It doesn't appear in the markdown in the editor, nor in the preview below it.

What is going on here??? Where is this text coming from?

I did have a look in the browser's console with my limited knowledge, and didn't find anything exceptional. Just that the text is in a `<p>` tag inside the post-body `<div>`:

[image]

Comment: Just to confirm, the `<p>Hi <strong>@dany</strong>:</p>` is definitely in the HTML supplied by SE, so it's not something on your machine which is changing it.

Comment: I also made sure and just in case disabled all userscripts - still the same...

Comment: My assumption: nowadays salutations [are automatically removed from posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989), but that post was rendered (and the HTML stored) before that was in place. But it sets in when you try to edit it. I think if you edit something and then change it back to trigger an update, it will be fixed.

Comment: and the response from the `/edit-inline` endpoint does not contain the prefix - so definitely something on SE's side of things.

Comment: @Ivar So what you're is that any edit applied will remove it? I guess I'll try it, for science...

Comment: I see Catija ninja'd. Expecting an answer anytime now...

Comment: And, now that it's been edited, we no longer have access to the data for testing.

Comment: So catija already made the edit and now that salutation is not there. But interestingly it doesn't show in the diff of the edit and not even in the first revision (nor in the source of it)

Comment: @Makyen half-temped to close as not reproducible)

Comment: @OlegValter Ivar found a matching duplicate. But yeah, especially since I didn't post any images, this would really seem weird to any future readers...

Comment: @Tomerikoo eh, I was just joking since Catija ninja-edited the post) Ivar found a good duplicate target indeed - I was about to VTC too on their suggestion when you accepted it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have a tool to reduce greetings in posts that automatically removes them if they're detected. This was clearly created after the post in question was drafted. As such, the cached render includes the salutation but the actual post content does not. The way we update the render is to edit. Fortunately in this case there's a matching signature which isn't automatically removed, so removing that will refresh the saved version and actually remove the greeting.